# Can i copy paste the entire code folder in SVN repository

Tags: php, windows, linux, svn

I am building a website and my public_html is under SVN. Now i dont know much about SVN.

This weekend i copied the whole site to my windows computer and i made few changes to site.

I have made changes under SRC directory.

Now can i just copy paste that whole folder in main webiste  SRC folder. As that folder is shared on my windows XP , i can just replace that. Or i can remove the old one and replace with this new one.

I just don't want to break the SVN . which method is safe , so that other coders on diff folders don't get affected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to `commit / ci` your changes instead of deleting the ones on repository.

Next time you MOVE files, use `SVN MOVE` command . Also, you might consider updating to Git?

Here is a link to SVN commands for you to get started :)

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/edguide/chapter03.html#ch03-introduction

Comment: Updating to `git` is indeed recommended.

Comment: But, I understand the asker. However, I am not sure why some corporate are still skeptic about it.

Comment: I also do not see reason enough to move to git. Maybe it would suffice to just check out a local working copy on "his windows XP" and only update the real site, when changes are approved. (Just the way svn is supposed to be used). Copying files out of a working folder for change is never a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you do not touch the .svn folder(s) you should be fine. Copying another file with the same name is just like editing it. Once you copied the files, you can commit your changes.

**However:** If other people may have made changes, then make sure that you copy your files BEFORE updating from the repository (then the update will try to merge with your changes)! If you copy your files onto the already updates files, you will overwrite the other peoples changes - effectively undoing them (but you will not notice, because you can commit).

Answer (score 1):

If you copy & paste you should delete all .svn files and folder in public_html and subdirectories.

...or you could install an SVN client on the server and run "svn update" (you may want to restrict the .svn files & folders from being accessed by the general public)

Comment: but i think if i copy paste only files with same name will be overwritten , .svn stays there as i don't have those in new folders. they are just plain php files. can i copy paste ???

Answer (score 1):

The "SVN Way" is do a commit (`svn commit`) of the *SRC* directory from your Windows computer and then do an update (`svn update`) in the *SRC* directory inside the server *public_html* directory.

When you copied the *SRC* directory you cloned the working copy. You can just used them both as normal working copies and use the repository to sync them.